# How jqueryui autocomplete works with Json?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with jquery ui...

This code sample is not working and i don't see why, have you got an idea why ?

js :

```
    $('#form_tags').autocomplete({
    source: function (requete, reponse) { // les deux arguments représentent les données nécessaires au plugin
        $.ajax({
            url: '/blog/tags.json', // on appelle le script JSON
            dataType: 'json', // on spécifie bien que le type de données est en JSON            
            success: function (donnee) {
                console.log(donnee);
                reponse($.map(donnee, function (objet) {
                    return objet.TagLib,objet.TagLib; // on retourne cette forme de suggestion
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

json :

```
[{"tagLib":"Miel"},{"tagLib":"bon"},{"tagLib":"louis"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
reponse($.map(donnee, function (objet) {
  return objet.TagLib,objet.TagLib; // on retourne cette forme de suggestion
}));
```

to this:

```
reponse($.map(donnee, function (objet) {
  return {
    label: objet.tagLib,
    value: objet.tagLib,
  };
}));
```

[Here is working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JnG1Ag0TS48soQfbtDpQ?p=preview)